# Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider' to type 'NHibernate.Cache.ICacheProvider'

Tags: nhibernate, caching, castle-activerecord, syscache

I'm using `NHibernate 2.1.2` via Castl ActiveRecord. I wanted to set up second level cache using `SysCache`. But I got error:

Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider' to type 'NHibernate.Cache.ICacheProvider'.

How can I correct this?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. We are using that provider without any problem. How have you configured it? Are you using the ActiveRecordFacility?

Comment: Sounds like a version mismatch. Make sure the cache provider assembly is the one for NHibernate 2.1.2

Comment: @Mauricio: I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000, Castle.ActiveRecord 2.1.2.6725 and NHibernate.Caches.SysCache 2.1.2.4000. Is it the problem?

Comment: @jishi: My configurations is based on followings: http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/advanced/secondLevelCache.html and http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/using-syscache-as-secondary-cache-in-nhibernate I'm not using `ActiveRecordFacility`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It was a nasty problem from ours. My team have merged all Castle ActiveRecord related assemblies together with `ilmerge.exe` and suppose named it `Company.NHibernate.dll`. I have not merged `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.dll` with `Company.NHibernate.dll`. I have just put `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.dll` alongside of `Company.NHibernate.dll` and mentioned name of `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache` in `provider_class`.

When I merged `NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.dll` with `Company.NHibernate.dll` and mentioned name of `Company.NHibernate.dll` in `provider_class` instead, everything went OK.

Thanks all users that tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you have some assemblies locally in your project and others in the GAC which have a version mismatch as Mauricio is saying. Make sure that NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.dll is in your bin folder (for your website), is the correct version and check that you don't have it in the GAC.